# Arcpy.AddJoin error

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, table, error-000732, error-000840

I am trying to populate a table by joining an excel sheet to a featureclass and using field calculator to populate the fields, but I am getting errors for the arcpy.addjoin_management.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\vincent.law\Documents\CW_Peter_Lougheed_PP.gdb'
jointable = r'C:\Users\vincent.law\Documents\BoultenCreek1.xlsx\Sheet1$'

arcpy.AddField_management("Campsite", "Campground_NameCampsite_Number", "TEXT","","","","", "NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Campsite", "Campground_NameCampsite_Number", "!Campground_Name!+ !Campsite_Number!", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("Campsite", "Campground_NameCampsite_Number", "jointable", "Campground_NameCampsite_Number", "KEEP_ALL")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Campsite","Campsite.Pad_Length","[Sheet1$.Pad_Length]","VB", "")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Campsite","Campsite.Pad_Min_Width","[Sheet1$.Pad_Min_Width]","VB", "")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Campsite","Campsite.Campsite_Type","[Sheet1$.Campsite_Type]","VB", "")
RemoveJoin_management("Campsite")
DeleteField_management("Campsite", "Campground_NameCampsite_Number")
```

> File
>    "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py",
>    line 326, in RunScript
>        exec codeObject in **main**.**dict**   File "\goa\desktop\T_Z\vincent.law\Desktop\campsite.py", line 8, in
>    
>       arcpy.AddJoin_management("Campsite", "Campground_NameCampsite_Number", "jointable",
>    "Campground_NameCampsite_Number", "KEEP_ALL")   File "C:\Program Files
>    (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6120, in
>   AddJoin
>        raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. The value cannot be a feature class
>
> ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
>
> ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog Layer.
>
> ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.
>
> WARNING 000970: The join field Campground_NameCampsite_Number in the join table Campsite is not indexed. To improve performance, we recommend that an index be created for the join field in the join table.
>
> ERROR 000732: Join Table: Dataset jointable does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (AddJoin).

Answer (score 2):

Joins need to be on layers, not feature classes. There's a hint in the error message - *The value cannot be a feature class*

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("campsite", "campsite_layer")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("campsite_layer", ......
```

Comment: I have added the two line, but now I am getting ERROR 000732: Join Table: Dataset C:\Users\vincent.law\Documents\BoultenCreek1.xlsx\Sheet1$ does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (AddJoin).

Comment: If it's processing in the background, xlsx is not supported: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Background_Geoprocessing_64_bit/002100000040000000/

Comment: Also check your xlsx file against these requirements: http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008903

Comment: At least for ERROR 000732 you need to convert the excel spread sheet to an Arc readable format. You can view excel tables in catalog but you cannot interact with them. I would say export to DBF or a comma delimited TXT file and then import that into arcmap. Here is a tool to convert excel to database table. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/excel-to-table.htm